# Using XAML How do I add columns to a TabItem

Tags: wpf, xaml

How do I add columns to a TabItem, so that I can resize the columns with a splitter and have the controls  stacked in each column resize at the same time?

I created the following XAML. I thought as the splitters were resized the buttons would resize with each column.

```
    <Grid Background="LightBlue">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" >
        <StackPanel>
          <TextBlock Text="Multiple items go here as the header" />
        </StackPanel>
      </DockPanel>
      <TabControl Grid.Row="1" Background="Beige" >
        <TabItem x:Name="Tab1" Header="Tab One" >
          <DockPanel>
            <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
              <TextBlock Text="Header for this tab goes here" />
            </StackPanel>
            <Grid>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Background="Aqua" Width="4" />
              <GridSplitter Grid.Column="3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Background="Aqua" Width="4" />
              <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" >
                <Button Content="Column 1" />
              </StackPanel>
              <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" >
                <Button Content="Column 2" />
              </StackPanel>
              <StackPanel Grid.Column="4" >
                <Button Content="Column 3" />
              </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
          </DockPanel>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="Tab2" Header="Tab Two" ></TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="Tab3" Header="Tab Three" ></TabItem>
      </TabControl>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"` to your GridSplitters and it will work.

[GridSplitter.ResizeBehavior Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridsplitter.resizebehavior(v=vs.110).aspx)'s default value is [GridResizeBehavior.BasedOnAlignment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridresizebehavior(v=vs.110).aspx) which means

> Space is redistributed based on the value of the HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment properties.

*Whatever that means.* But you want PreviousAndNext which means

> For a horizontal GridSplitter, space is redistributed between the rows that are above and below the row that is specified for the GridSplitter. For a vertical GridSplitter, space is redistributed between the columns that are to the left and right of the column that is specified for the GridSplitter.